# Show that an algebra is a linear algebraic subgroup in $GL(A)$, $A$ being a finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb C$ with unit 1. Let $G$ be the set of all $g \in A$ such that $g$ is invertible in $A$. For $z \in A$ let $L_a \in$ End$(A)$ be the operator of left multiplication by $a$. Define $\phi: G \rightarrow GL(A)$ by $\phi (g)=L_g$.

**Show** that $\phi(G)$ is a linear algebraic subgroup in $GL(A)$

Hint: To find a set of algebraic equations for $\phi (G)$, prove that $T \in$ End$(A)$ commutes with all the operators of right multiplication by elements of $A$ iff $T=L_a$ for some $a \in A$

Been stuck with this question for a very long time. Any help would be much appreciated!